# Display comic strip in Imageview

Tags: android, listview, imageview

i use Universal image loader to load some imageview(large height) to listview.
this is listview(custom for zoom in/out) in activity:

```
<noname.test1.CustomListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listviewImg" />
```

this is list_img.xml for listview:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageview1">
</ImageView>
```

this is image i want to load (size 400px X 5312px):
[link](http://img.truyen8.mobi/2013/1015/sieu-nhan-cuoc-xeng_36808_1.jpg)

this is result:
[image]

I want image when show is full screen or larger.
How to fix it?

Comment: what you want it to be?

Comment: @sumandas : i want image will show full in screen or larger

Comment: add `scaleType="centerCrop"`, maybe this is what you want.

Comment: Just a small note, you aware if your image is of smaller size forcing it to bloat will make it look hazy and pixelated and it seems to be comics and graphics so might ruin the look. You want it?

Comment: @L. Swiffter: i was try, but it show a part of image, not full image.

Comment: @sumandas : yes, please help me!

Comment: @1234abcd please put backgoud color of ImageView  .and check is it show in same as like drawable image?

Comment: You're trying to show a comic strip? Why are you even using a ListView? You only have one really long image

Comment: @cricket_007 I think it is multiple images, it is all sticked together so looks like a big lengthy image, but seems these are pages, mark the border colors, just no separation so looks one file.

Comment: Try to scaleType="fitxy" or put full xml  list_img.xml and CustomListView.java

Comment: @sumandas Well, "size 400px X 5312px", and if you click the link in the question... It's one really tall image

Comment: Then may be it is just image view, i thought them to be strips/pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create  this class and use this instead of imageView

```
/**
 * Created by farazkhonsari on 1/26/16.
*/

public class ScaledImageView extends ImageView {

public ScaledImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ScaledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ScaledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    try {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

        if (drawable == null) {
            setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
        } else {

            int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                int width = measuredWidth;
                int height = width *  drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() / drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

and use this class in layout like this:

```
<ir.farazGroup.YeJoke.tools.ScaledImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/c"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change scaleType of imageViwe and set adjustViewBound true:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/imageview1"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true">
</ImageView>
```

you can try other option for scaleType and see which one is good for you!

and you can read about scaleType here:
[scaleTypes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: [Set this inside onCreate or onCreateView after inflating the list]

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id. imageview1);

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(metrics);
float screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
imageView.getLayoutParams().width = (int) screenWidth; // Takes the whole screen width
```

Answer (score 0):

try this i'll hope i will help you

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/imageView" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:src="@drawable/locked_image"
   android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```